# How to perform the parameterization of the following figure?

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

This topic has been a bit tedious for me but in my attempt I found a possible complex function that represents this trajectory is:

**z(t) = (2i - 4i t) u(t) + (2r t) u(t-1/2) + (-2ir + (2r-ir) (t-1)) u(t-1)**

Where **u(t)** is the Heaviside unit step function. This complex function is divided into two parts to represent the two curves of the trajectory:

The first part **(2i - 4i t) u(t) + (2r t) u(t-1/2)** represents the curve that starts from the negative "Y" axis at the point "$-2ir$", goes to the axis "X" at the "$2r$" point and then goes to the positive y axis at the "2ir" point. The Heaviside unit step function is used to ensure that the first part of the function is only evaluated on the interval **[0, 1]**.

The second part **(-2ir + (2r-ir) (t-1)) u(t-1)** represents the smallest curve that starts at the point "ir", goes to the "X" axis at the point "$r$" and goes to the negative "Y" axis at the "-ir" point. The Heaviside unit step function is used to ensure that the second part of the function is only evaluated on the interval **[1, 2]**.

The arrow that connects the end point of the second curve with the initial point of the first curve is represented by the discontinuity in the function at $t=1$.

I don't know if the above is a valid or correct answer, I appreciate everything you can correct.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your question is very clear. Don't pay attention to this robot with low QI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your computation looks very correct.

But there is a simpler way, avoiding in particular to use Heaviside function. Here is how.

[image]

*Rectangle $R$ and its image, "bended" by exponential function, the half-annulus $A$, in the case $r=1.5$.*

Let us parametrize a rectangle $R$ with complex vertices $z_1,z_2,\overline{z_2},\overline{z_1}$ (see figure) where

$$z_1=\ln(r)+\frac{\pi}{2}i, \ \ \ z_2=\ln(2r)+\frac{\pi}{2}i,$$

then transform it using complex exponential function :

$$\color{red}{z} \to \color{blue}{Z=e^z}$$

giving "in a natural way" the half-annulus $A$.

Such a transformation is called a "conformal mapping" because (in particular) angles are preserved.

It works because

- the vertices of $R$ are mapped onto the vertices of $A$:

$$\begin{cases}Z_1&=&e^{z_1}&=&e^{\ln(r)+\frac{\pi}{2}i}&=&ri\\Z_2&=&e^{z_2}&=&e^{\ln(2r)+\frac{\pi}{2}i}&=&2ri\end{cases}$$

with preservation of the 4 right angles.

- the horizontal (resp. vertical) sides of $R$ are mapped onto the vertical (resp circular arcs) of $A$.

Matlab program having produced the image :

```
 clear all;close all;hold on;
 r=1.5;k=log(2)/2;axis(2.1*r*[0,1,-1,1]);axis equal;grid on;
 plot([0,5],[0,0],'k');plot([0,0],[-3,3]*pi/2,'k'); % axes
 t=0:0.01:2*pi;m=max([abs(cos(t));abs(sin(t))]);
 % allowing a (classical) parameterization of the... 
 S=exp(i*t)./m; % ...square with sidelength 2 centered in O
 R=k*real(S)+(pi/2)*imag(S)*i+log(r)+k; transf. of S into ...
 plot(R,'r'); % ... rectangle R
 plot(exp(R),'b'); % half-annulus A
```